# Are there an alternative to Deep Zoom for Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, deepzoom, multiscaleimage

I have to work with a lot of images (high resolutions) and the best approach was to use Deep Zoom but it is not available for Windows Store app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050(v=vs.95).aspx

Does an alternative exist? 
If not, what could be the best approach to create a custom control similar to Deep Zoom?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with C#; is that the language you're using? I understand Windows store apps can also use HTML5. If that's available to you, then you can use OpenSeadragon, which is a JavaScript version of Deep Zoom: http://openseadragon.github.com

Comment: Thank you for the link but I'm currently developing with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Deep Zoom for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128695/Deep-Zoom-for-WPF), you can create your own with help of it. WinRT XAML Toolkit has planning to release MultiScaleImage control for Deep Zoom support. They are also following that article.

Comment: I found also this article before asking but as you say MultiScaleImage is not yet available and we don't know when it will be

Comment: Yeah, but I encourage you to develop it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I Found this project :

http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/

It is a Bing Maps like but you can choose your own source. I'm currently analyzing how it works.

I hope it could help some people here!